# how doesn't work the cast in Java?

Tags: java

I have the next code:

```
if(lineaCurvaPintada){
  FiguraGeometrica f;
  MiLineaCurva c;
 (MiLineaCurva)vShape.get(vShape.size()-1).setCtrlx(evt.getPoint().x);
}
```

Where FiguraFeometrica is an abstact class. MiLineaCurva extends from FiguraGeometrica.
setCtrlx is a method of MiLineaCurva class.

vShape is an array of FiguraGeometrica.

Why do I can not access to MiLineaCurva methods?
The error that Netbeans is give me is: Can't not find method in class FiguraGeometrica.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parenthesis is the problem here. You're type casting the result of `vShape.get(vShape.size()-1).setCtrlx(evt.getPoint().x)`. Fix the code with this:

```
((MiLineaCurva)vShape.get(vShape.size()-1)).setCtrlx(evt.getPoint().x);
^-----------------------------------------^
```

Note that if the object in `vShape.get(vShape.size()-1)` is not of type `MiLineaCurva` then you will get a `ClassCastException`.